# Cannot install jenssegers/laravel-mongodb Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, composer-php

I am working with Laravel 5.1 and having problem installing jenssegers/laravel-mongodb.

https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB

I am using Laravel 5.1 and PHP 5.5.12 and when I run

```
composer  require jenssegers/mongodb
```

[image]

I see the error that it requires mongodb version 1.0.0 above? And needs PHP extension enabled?

But I already have that, here's my php info

[image]

Comment: Run `php -m` and see if the required modules are listed.

Comment: I tried to run it and indeed no mongodb in there. What should I look into? My DLL and in my PHP Info it's there. Even in my php.ini it there already

Comment: Look for `php.ini` file path in php info and make sure it's the right one you are editing, you need to restart php if you haven't already.

Comment: You're right. It's working now. I did not notice I have two php.ini files. Works now